# I need to save the html website state

Tags: javascript, html, database

I am making a website for my dad, since i cant host it, i was just going to send him an html file he can open on his computer, I need to save the website state so when he comes back on he can resume, any thoughts?

Comment: "Local storage" in the browser seems like a viable option for storing data.

Comment: in addition to David's comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Comment: should the website never be hosted? or do you just want be able to let your father test before the site is finished?

Comment: i dont intend on publishing it, i cant really pay for that